# downgrade Java 1.8u121 ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

Подскажите как перейти с версии openjdk 1.8.0_131 на версию openjdk 1.8.0_121

сервер Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

```
~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131- b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

если можно пошагово чтобы не убить сервер, тк подобное буду делать первый раз, заранее спасибо.

Comment: ну так пакеты-то [так и лежат в репозитории](http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-8/). просто скачайте и установите пакеты нужных вам версий. предварительно удалив более новые версии пакетов. а чтобы они не были вновь переустановлены при обновлении, [сделайте для них `apt-mark hold`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/yakkety/man8/apt-mark.8.html)

Comment: а зачем вам потребовалось даунгрейдиться, если не секрет?